# Two sequential subscriptions on two separate observables Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have an issue with two sequential subscriptions on two separate observables in Angular 2.
I am trying to:

1. get location from coordinates
2. attach this location to my json
3. send json to server

The way I do it is I believe wrong:

```
this._locationService.geocode(this.location.latitude, this.location.longitude).
        subscribe(position => {
            this.location.city = this.findAddressPart(position, "locality", "long");
            this.location.country = this.findAddressPart(position, "country", "long");
            this._locationService.updateLocation(this.location)
                .subscribe(
                    location => {
                        this.location = location;
                        this.submitted = true;
                        this.submitting = false;
                    }
                );
        });
```

This way my DOM is updating only 5-10s after I actually fetch the location.

Comment: Did you try to run this in angular zone? using this.zone.run( () => {})
You should only run the location assignments inside the zone

Comment: How does that work?

Comment: Please refer to this article:
http://www.joshmorony.com/understanding-zones-and-change-detection-in-ionic-2-angular-2/

Comment: What is the actual problem?  What is currently not happening that should be?

Comment: Thanks @galvan! The problem was that my code inside second subscription was working outside of angular and not running change detection. I ran it in zone.run block and it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a problem with how long your solution takes to update. Unfortunately there's no way around this unless you restructure how your `_locationService` uses data. Currently you have:

1. get geocode from latitude and longitude
2. wait for request to finish
3. set data from request #1 to location
4. get update data from location
5. wait for request to finish
6. set update location
7. update DOM w/ updated location

There's two requests chained together. If possible, I would combine the two functions into one call on your backend so that you can call something like

```
this._locationService.geocode(this.location.latitude, this.location.longitude).
        subscribe(location => {
            this.location = location;
            this.submitted = true;
            this.submitting = false;
        });
```

Of course, this would only work if your server contains the data for serving this type of request. If you server also has to make HTTP calls then changing it to the above would be moot.

If the above isn't possible, you could update your DOM after the first request has finished. If everything goes well, the `updateLocation` function will just return the same location that was sent to server anyway, right? You could update the DOM with the locally available values and instead of updating the DOM on success of the second function, only change them if there was an error. This would make your response time seem 50% faster. Something like this.

```
this._locationService.geocode(this.location.latitude, this.location.longitude).
        subscribe(position => {
            this.location.city = this.findAddressPart(position, "locality", "long");
            this.location.country = this.findAddressPart(position, "country", "long");
            // SET DOM HERE using this.location values
            this._locationService.updateLocation(this.location)
                .subscribe(
                    location => {
                        this.location = location;
                        // optionally SET DOM HERE again
                        this.submitted = true;
                        this.submitting = false;
                    }, 
                    error => {
                        // SET DOM HERE reflecting error
                    }
                );
        });
```